# How can I cache a page manually in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am trying to create a site in RoR and have enabled caching for some pages and actions. The related DB may not accessible every time and hence using the cache is very much required. Hence I cant wait for someone to actually visit the page, render it and then cache it. Instead I want whatever is cache-able to be cached manually, programatically. Is it actually possible or is it that caching is completely automatic in RoR?

Comment: When should it be cached? What's the trigger?

Comment: I dont mind even putting a "cache it now" button in the admin page of the app that caches the pages. But how will I handle that trigger so that things get cached?

Answer (score 0):

The lazy* solution would be to visit the page as part of your deployment process with lynx, or even curl.  That would trigger the cache event from the outside, but at a time of your choosing.

(*) lazy in a good way, I hope.

Comment: :) But is the cache event so inaccessible from within?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [page_cache plugin](http://github.com/eliotsykes/page_cache). Seems like this is what you need.

Comment: page-cache plugin is being used. But it doesnt give the whole control from within application. Rake has to be called by cron. Not exactly what I wanted but may be that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing manual caching triggering now, and looks like you can use built-in API of [actionpack-page_caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) plugin to manually trigger the creating of pages cache. You need to use `cache_page(content, path, extension = nil, gzip = Zlib::BEST_COMPRESSION)` function with attributes (look line 80 at https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching/blob/master/lib/action_controller/caching/pages.rb). Here I made sample action, which is iterating over some collection and making cache of "show" method of each item of this collection.

```
def precompile
    @pages = Page.all
    @pages.each do |page|
      @page = page
      cache_page(render_to_string(template: 'pages/show'), url_for(action: :show, id: @page, only_path: true))
    end
    redirect_to '/'
end
```

The `url_for(action: :show, id: @page, only_path: true)` part of my code is not very clean, but it is the first version of code which is working as I needed, any refactor are welcome.
Also, this code will overwrite the cache file every time it is fired, without checking for any changes or expirations.

Answer (score -1):

Ref :- [Link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

```
class ProductsController < ActionController 
  caches_page :index  
  def index

  end
end
```

set perform caching to true in your enviorment config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Comment: -1: see quote from the link you provided: "The first time anyone requests products/index, Rails will generate a file called index.html"
 but the author doesn't want to wait until someone visits the page, he wants it to be cached in advance.

Comment: @neutrino: exactly. But is it possible?